# Postgres trigger to update records of several parent tables based on values of a many-to-many join table referencing those parent table records

Tags: postgresql, trigger, many-to-many

I have a PostgreSQL 15 join table `schema.m2mjointable` to link records of several parent tables (`schema.table_a`, `schema.table_b`, ...) with other records of those same parent tables:

| id | ref_table | ref_id | rep_table | rep_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IDENTITY | TEXT | INT | TEXT | INT |
| ---------- | -------------- | -------- | -------------- | -------- |
| 1 | table_a | 1 | table_a | 2 |
| 2 | table_a | 1 | table_c | 3 |
| 3 | table_a | 4 | table_b | 7 |
| 4 | table_b | 5 | table_a | 8 |
| 5 | table_b | 9 | table_b | 11 |
| 6 | table_c | 7 | table_b | 11 |

In the parent tables (`schema.table_a`, `schema.table_b`, ...), there is always a boolean field named `referenced` which should tell if the record `i` of table `n` is at least referenced *once* by the pair of columns `ref_table` and `ref_id` in this join table. If that's the case it should be set to `TRUE`. It should be set to `FALSE` if it's never present in this pair of columns.

How could I build a trigger function to update the `referenced` field of the parent tables with such trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER schema.set_referenced_state_biudt
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON schema.m2mjointable
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.set_referenced_state();
```

```sql
BEGIN;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.set_referenced_state()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
$$
BEGIN
   -- set the BOOL value of the "referenced" field to TRUE or FALSE
   -- in the record id=value_of(ref_id) of the parent table=value_of(ref_table) 
   -- corresponding to those values of the record being currently inserted/updated/deleted
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I currently achieved, it's working, but probably not perfect so feel free to improve this idea if you think there are drawbacks:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.set_referenced_state()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I.%I SET "referenced" = FALSE WHERE id = $1', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, OLD.ref_table) USING OLD.ref_id;
    RETURN OLD;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' OR TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I.%I SET "referenced" = TRUE WHERE id = $1', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, NEW.ref_table) USING NEW.ref_id;
    RETURN NEW;
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```